# Flutter I cannot type on a screen

Tags: flutter, text, uitextfield

I made a login screen using TextField widget. However, I cannot type on the screen even though on the youtube video that I watched, this person could type with the same code. I could not figure out why so it would be really appreciated if someone tells me how enable this screen to be typed on it.

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Email',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Lobster'),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.deepPurple[200],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black45,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    offset: Offset(0, 10))
              ]),
          height: 55.0,
          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter your Email',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Lobster'),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              prefix: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.email,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: app works as expected when I tried. Do you see any error when you try to access the text field? If so please post it here.

Comment: It does not show any errors, I just cannot type on the screen